# Technical analysis off/on topic? Text to include

Tags: discussion

The topic has been discussed at [Do we want technical analysis questions?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/669/do-we-want-technical-analysis-questions) and so it seems "yes."

This question is posted to seek the text to add it to our On Topic page. One line, crisp enough to make the point, and hint at the limit of the topic, the point where an otherwise tech question is really too broad or too specific to one stock, etc.

Update - As I noted in a comment below, I feel that a change to the On-Topic should have more dialog when it's more than a simple clarification such as adding 'insurance', which was never in question, just not explicitly stated. The current answer looks fine to me, and I will go with that wording if there's no further input from other members. I'm going to wait until 10/10, so this will have been open for input for 3 weeks.

10/10 Update - As promised, I've updated the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Again, it's not cast in stone, typos and minor corrections always welcome. Anything that actually adds or deletes, such as this, will need some member discussion first.

Comment: @Victor May be you could get something as you have most score on Technical Analysis

Answer (score 3):

For context, here's part of the existing list at [What topics can I ask about here?](//money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Investing & Saving**
>
> - Personal investing and asset allocation
> - Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals
> - Strategies for earning more money
> - Insurance, including life, home, auto, health
> - Use of software for managing one's finances. (Not recommendations, just questions regarding specific software)
>
> **Spending Wisely**
>
> - [...]
>
> **Sole Proprietorships**
>
> - [...]

---

The best-fit spot for a mention of technical analysis is in the first section—and yet we make no mention of trading, stocks, or any other kind of analysis. I think simply adding technical analysis would leave some obvious gaps.

My suggestion is to broaden the title of the section and add points as follows:

#### Saving, Investing, & Trading

- [... as above ...]
- Securities trading and investing, whether long- or short-term, as practiced by retail traders and investors. (Excludes specific security recommendations, stock tips/discussion, forecasts.)
- Investing and trading strategies, including fundamental and technical analysis and other techniques, as practiced by retail traders and investors.

Comment: "Stock" should probably be something more broad, such as "financial" or "financial instrument" or "exchange product".

Comment: @dg99 "Securities", then?

Comment: Nice answer. Given that this is soliciting an update to the on-topic wording, I'd like to see more responses, or comments on this answer. Or at least my fellow mod's agreement as well. The topic hasn't been explicitly added to the page in over 6 years, another week or two is no issue.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I completely agree. (Also why I marked it a wiki. Feel free to edit.)

Comment: Thanks. It looks fine to me, I just don't want to ever touch On Topic without waiting and getting more member input. Especially since this is a topic I don't really follow. (I did add 'insurance', but that wasn't even close to controversy, it seemed am oversight it wasn't listed)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Yes, good call.

Comment: For the technical analysis butter want to add ...( again excluding specific recommendations and evaluation of conditions) .  We want to avoid questions that are entirely pasting of a chart and asking "is it time to sell?"